# Jquery to run mp4 files in firefox,IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, html, mp4

Hi I am trying to play a mp4 file in IE,chrome and Firefox.
It works fine in IE and chrome but not in Firefox.
I know firefox doesnt support MP4. But the requirement is playing an mp4 only. Can anyone share me the jquery to make it possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What jQuery has to do with that anyway?

Comment: jQuery is very clever but it's not magic.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox I can tell you that is simply not possible without plugins like Flash.

About chrome AFIK just a subset of MP4 is supported, you need to check that you use the right colorspace.

The IE9+ has AFIK a native support, there you can in include a video simple with a video HTML5 tag.

You can also use the [jw-player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) it combinds both worlds: HTML5 and Flash.

Comment: Can you tell me what type of flash supports it.